# I can't find the old Garageband loop "Adrenaline Electronica". Where did it go?

Tags: garage-band

I redownloaded Garageband earlier, but I can't find the loop called "Adrenaline Electronica". Has Apple removed some of their old loops?

Comment: http://www.macloops.com/
I can't find it either! 
The only link where it's been mentioned is this one: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22313/appropriate-background-music-for-a-webapp-screencastMay be they had to remove it because people were getting ill about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuY_Rkmq5i0